# Javascript: split a string accurately like this: /kick @Username "reason" BUT username can have special characters

Tags: javascript, regex, string

Here's my dilemma...

I want to be able to split a string that would look like this:

```
/ban @User "because I told you so"
```

However, the problem with using spaces, @, or quotation marks as delimiters for the string is that the user's name can contain a wide array of special characters.  AND, chances are, those special characters might be able to conflict with processing the command.

For example:

```
/ban @Person" "because why not"
```

Wouldn't work, nor would

```
/ban @Person"name" "reason"
```

How can I accurately process something like this when any of the characters I could use to split up the string could easily be emulated by the targeted user's name to break the command?  Is this even possible at all?  I'll be honest, RegExp is kind of daunting for me to understand or look at, so if this is a simple regex fix, I apologize :(

Thanks a ton to a solution, I now have a working processor:

```
    var yourRegex = /^@(.*?) "([^"]+)"$/;
```

Since I can already take the /ban out (other commands like /kick, etc. as it's not exclusively this one command) I just chopped that out of the regexp.  I also moved the @ symbol out since I don't need that to target the user.  Works 100% :D

Comment: I had to do something like this. My solution was to build a little parser, so for 'simple' names, you could just put the name there, but for anything more complex, you can quote it and if it contains quotes, the quotes can be escaped. A little more complex, but it works quite well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
/^\/ban (@.*?) "([^"]+)"$/
```

This will give you the username in the first subpattern (with leading `@` symbol, just move it outside the parentheses if you want to exclude it), and the reason in the second (without the quotes around it, move them inside the parens to include them).

Comment: I think the `.*?` can also be replaced with `.*` here.

Comment: Hey, I tested this out and it worked perfectly.  Thanks again -- now that I have a basis for what to add for getting @ Usernames, I can tweak it for other commands, e.g. /swap @ Username @ OtherUsername.  I'll accept your answer when it allows me to :P

Also, note I added the spaces because StackOverflow thinks I'm trying to notify people haha.

@pimvdb, what would that change?  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in the comments, I approached a similar task by using a minimal parser. Here's one in CoffeeScript, which compiles to JavaScript:

```
parse = (input) ->
  index = 0
  peek = -> input.charAt index
  advance = -> ++index; peek()
  advanceRP = ->
    last = peek()
    advance()
    return last
  collect = (regex) -> (advanceRP() while peek().match regex).join ''
  skipWhiteSpace = -> collect /\s/
  literal = ->
    result = collect /[@\w]/
    skipWhiteSpace()
    return result
  string = ->
    if peek() == '"'
      advance()
      result = []
      loop
        result.push collect /[^"]/
        advance()  # skip past closing quote
        if peek() is '"'  # and therefore an escape (double quote)
          result.push '"'
        else if peek().match /\s?/
          break  # whitespace or end of input; end of string
        else
          # neither another quote nor whitespace;
          # they probably forgot to escape the quote.
          # be lenient, here.
          result.push '"'
      skipWhiteSpace()
      result.join ''
    else
      literal()

  return error: 'does not start with slash' if peek() isnt '/'
  advance()
  command = literal()
  return error: 'command unrecognized' if command isnt 'ban'
  person = string()
  if peek() == '"'
    reason = string()
    return error: 'junk after end of command' if index < input.length
  else
    reason = input.substring index

  command: 'ban'
  person: person
  reason: reason
```

Try it out:

```
coffee> parse '/ban @person reason'
{ command: 'ban', person: '@person', reason: 'reason' }
coffee> parse '/ban "@person with ""escaped"" quotes" and the reason doesn\'t need "quotes"'
{ command: 'ban'
, person: '@person with "escaped" quotes'
, reason: 'and the reason doesn\'t even need "quotes"'
}
```